# Not able to change state on event trigger in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am calling an event on `react-native-voice` to recognize the speech and calling an API and setting the state. But when I am setting a new value to a state array the array only have the new value instead of having the previous value. This is my code

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
  results = [];
}
Voice.onSpeechResults = this.onSpeechResults;
}
```

and I have a event which is been triggered to call an API like this.

```
onSpeechResults = e => {
        this._startRecognizing();
        //var joined = this.state.results.concat();
        getProductListingService(e.value[0]).then(data=>{
            let demoVar = Object.values(data);
            var newArray = this.state.results;
            newArray.push(demoVar[1]);
            this.setState({
                results:newArray
            })
           this.setState({
               show:true
           });
        });

    };
```

But when setting the state I am only able to get the new element been pushed into the array instead of the previous state. I have tried using `concat`, `spread`, and setting a new array. Stuck, Please help. :(

Comment: Can you try `console.log(this.state.results);` before adding the new item to the `newArray`

Comment: The array is empty every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

First declare your state like:

```
this.state = {
  results: []; // Don't use = for properties
}
```

second notice that if you `setState()` with same values that it already has, it doesn't set the state(and call render function).

Comment: I am not using `=` and not using any render method

Comment: see ur constructor